# using the right side of the disjoint union properly

Tags: json, scala, either, circe

what's the best way to turn a Right[List] into a List

I will parse a Json String like so

```
val parsed_states = io.circe.parser.decode[List[List[String]]](source)
```

And that will create an value equivalent to this

```
val example_data = Right(List(List("NAME", "state"), List("Alabama", "01"), List("Alaska", "02"), List("Arizona", "04")))
```

I'm trying to grok `Right`, `Left`, `Either` and implement the best way to get a list of StateName, StateValue pairs out of that list above.

I see that any of these ways will give me what I need (while dropping the header):

```
val parsed_states = example_data.toSeq(0).tail
val parsed_states = example_data.getOrElse(<ProbUseNoneHere>).iterator.to(Seq).tail
val parsed_states = example_data.getOrElse(<ProbUseNoneHere>).asInstanceOf[Seq[List[String]]].tail
```

I guess I'm wondering if I should do it one way or another based on the possible behavior upstream coming out of `io.circe.parser.decode` or am I overthinking this. I'm new to the `Right`, `Left`, `Either` paradigm and not finding terribly many helpful examples.

in reply to @slouc

trying to connect the dots from your answer as they apply to this use case. so something like this?

```
    def blackBox: String => Either[Exception, List[List[String]]] = (url:String) => {
      if (url == "passalong") {
        Right(List(List("NAME", "state"), List("Alabama", "01"), List("Alaska", "02"), List("Arizona", "04")))
      }
      else Left(new Exception(s"This didn't work bc blackbox didn't parse ${url}"))
    }
    //val seed = "passalong"
    val seed = "notgonnawork"
    val xx: Either[Exception, List[List[String]]] = blackBox(seed)
    def ff(i: List[List[String]]) = i.tail
    val yy = xx.map(ff)
    val zz = xx.fold(
      _  => throw new Exception("<need info here>"),
      i => i.tail)
```

Comment: If the `Left` is an `Exception` then you might consider `Try` instead of `Either`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is in **not getting state name / state value pairs out of the `Either`**. They should be kept inside. If you want to, you can transform the `Either` type into something else (e.g. an `Option` by discarding whatever you possibly had on the left side), but don't destroy the effect. Something should be there to show that decoding could have failed; it can be an `Either`, `Option`, `Try`, etc. Eventually you will process left and right case accordingly, but this should happen as late as possible.

Let's take the following trivial example:

```
val x: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)
def f(i: Int) = i + 1
```

You might argue that you need to get the 42 out of the `Right` so that you can pass it to `f`. But that's not correct. Let's rewrite the example:

```
val x: Either[String, Int] = someFunction()
```

Now what? We have no idea whether we have a `Left` or a `Right` in value `x`, so we can't "get it out". Which integer would you obtain in case it's a `Left`? (if you really do have an integer value to use in that case, that's fair enough, and I will address that use case a bit later)

What you need to do instead is *keep the effect* (in this case `Either`), and you need to continue working in the context of that effect. It's there to show that there was a point in your program (in this case `someFunction()`, or decoding in your original question) that might have gone wrong.

So if you want to apply `f` to your potential integer, you need to `map` the effect with it (we can do that because `Either` is a functor, but that's a detail which probably exceeds the scope of this answer):

```
val x: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)
def f(i: Int) = i + 1

val y = x.map(value => f(value)) // Right(43)
val y = x.map(f) // shorter, point-free notation
```

and

```
val x: Either[String, Int] = someFunction()
def f(i: Int) = i + 1

// either a Left with some String, or a Right with some integer increased by 1
val y = x.map(f)
```

Then, at the very end of the chain of computations, you can handle the `Left` and `Right` cases; for example, if you were processing an HTTP request, then in case of `Left` you might return a 500, and in case of `Right` return a 200.

To address the use case with default value mentioned earlier - if you really want to do that, get rid of the `Left` and in that case resolve into some value (e.g. 0), then you can use `fold`:

```
def f(i: Int) = i + 1

// if x = Left, then z = 0
// if x = Right, then z = x + 1
val z = x.fold(_ => 0, i => i + 1)
```

Comment: I find this super helpful. Thank you! I'd like to try to fill in the gaps by applying this to my original example. Something like this I think (I'm missing how to pass along the exception error)

Comment: @wile-e-quixote You got the main idea and you're struggling with the final step - what to do with a `Left`. That's normal, because that step is indeed hard; it's always easier to just think about the happy path. In Java, common practice is to throw an exception and let the caller worry about it, but that's bad for many reasons. In FP, you carry the effect as long as you can.

Comment: @wile-e-quixote Note that you can turn one effect into another. For example, handling HTTP requests in most web frameworks (Play, finch, http4s, etc.) requires you to eventually return an asynchronous effect such as Future or scalaz/monix Task or cats IO etc., and the framework takes care of the rest (you never need to "unpack" it from the effect yourself). So if you're writing a function that computes an HTTP response, you can turn Either into an asynchronous effect (e.g. Future) that either succeeded with the result from Right or failed with the error from Left. You never have to "get out".

Comment: so I could turn that last step `zz = xx.fold(<L/R>)` into a Future and the advantage is that I run this process on many urls asynchronously without one exception stopping the whole thing? And that I can handle those urls that didn't parse separately in any which way I choose? 
Is there a trade off in obfuscating the original Exception? In your example and in my own attempt to connect the dots the `Left` is mapped to an arbitrary value/exception.

Comment: @wile-e-quixote No, there's no obfuscation of the original exception, because you can use the same one. For example, scalaz `Task` wraps around `Future[Throwable \/ A]`, so you can have your original exception on the left. Regarding questions about asynchronous handling, that topic is a bit bigger and it's definitely not part of your original question (perhaps we could move it to gitter or something). But yes, they all have in common the fact that you won't block the thread. The details would also depend on the exact library you're using (e.g. is the async computation eager or lazy).

Comment: @wile-e-quixote When it comes to asynchronous computations, cats-effect is not only a great library, but it has really nice documentation that explains most of the important concepts: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/basics.html

Comment: Nice. TY this has been most helpful :)